# Endgames: How was "maximum moves required" determined before tablebases?

Tags: endgame, calculation, mathematics

To use a simple example, tablebases show that KQ vs. K is won in at most ten moves. But chess books going back many decades, well before tablebases, say the same thing. How was this calculated?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing was calculated. They arrived at their results by trial and error.

Some guy would start with a seemingly disadvantageous position and tried to find the shortest mate. His result remained valid until the next guy found a more disadvantageous position or a quicker mate.

A long time later, engines became powerful enough to calculate simple endgames like K+Q v K simply by exhausting all possibilities, but by that time technology was also advanced enough to create the first tablebases.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it *is* calculated by tablebases. I can't imagine anybody declaring a definitive number for the minimum moves needed to achieve checkmate with KQ vs. K.

Comment: Well, then you should look into some old books ... ;-)

Comment: The same books that claimed K+Q vs K+2B to be a draw?

Comment: To be fair, there is a big difference between KQ-K and KQ-KBB. But yes, those books.

Comment: And how useful are those numbers? If you can mate with KQ vs K in about ten moves, you know you understand it. Likewise if you can consistently do KBN vs K in less than 50. There is nothing comparable for KQ vs KBB. The useful information was on the whole produced mostly by human beings. 

Admittedly, KQ vs KR is a marginal case. And, yes, I do know about John Nunn's work.